# Add string with List to a multiline textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to add a `list` and a `string` in a `textbox` with this code

```
ilaninfotextbox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ilantextinner, combinelist);
```

`ilantextinner` is a `string` and shows correctly on the textbox

`ilantextinner` is a `List<string>` with 20 lines in it

But `ilantextinner` list is showing like this in the textbox:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

How can I show the contents of `ilantextinner` in the textbox?

Note: If I use only `ilantextinner` contents are shown correctly.

Comment: `ilaninfotextbox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, String.Join(',', lantextinner.ToArray()), combinelist);`

Comment: Please simply create a [mcve]. You're telling a lot about your code, but what you tell is incorrect or incomplete at best, and writing a small example that actually compiles will greatly help towards getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to Join the List, to make it a single string:

```
string joinedList = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, combinelist);
```

Then you join this string to the `TextBox` string:

```
ilaninfotextbox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ilantextinner, joinedList);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Join` function have 5 overloads. This is the one that's called using your code:

```
public static String Join(String separator, params object[] values);
```

**What does it tell us?**

This method receives a `object` array after the separator, and since it is using the `params` keyword, the method actually receives this on the **values** parameter:

```
new object[] { ilantextinner, combinelist };
```

The method will "loop" only through the objects found on the values parameter and call it's `ToString()`.

**How to solve it?**

I would do something like that to reach the results you want:

```
combinelist.Insert(0, ilantextinner);
ilaninfotextbox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, combinelist);
```

The first line adds the `ilantextinner` to the start of the list, so you can simply use the `Join` overload that expects an `IEnumerable<string>`.

See this link for more understanding on the `params` keyword: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to use

```
string.join(string sepeator,params string[] value);
```

But because you don't convert List To Array of string the compiler thinked that you would to use

```
string.join(string sepeator,params object[] value);
```

So convert List to array of string

```
ilaninfotextbox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, String.Join(' ', lantextinner.ToArray()), combinelist);
```